# Css3 animations problems with horizontal site over 4000px width

Tags: html, animation, webkit, css

I'm currently working on a horizontal site looking to make something like http://www.thehorizontalway.com and was looking to add in some great new css3 animations but have found that 4000px wide is a magic number that breaks the animations (appears the divs position stops working) I've looked into the -webkit-box modeling and -webkit-box-orient:horizontal but neither of these seem to be a fix (and can't find slot on the webkit box)

Does anyone know why this is happening and what I could do to

Comment: Can you provide a code example the demonstrates the problems that you are experiencing?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about the 4000px, never assumed it would be an issue with animation.

Try Using percentages:

The wrapper = width:100%; height:100%; = What you're seeing on screen at a time, 
20 pages = width:2000 % height:100%; which will be the mask of the entire site,
I believe these should be position:absolute; to prevent conflicts;

Then you will probably want to put some divs in per page content:
width:100%; height:100%; float:left; with page link #id's as you know.

It won't make your site look like "The Horizontal Way" It can be considered as a 
better method as you can make your content fit to every page jump & re-size.

Oh and...Why horizontal... you can stack your page content to give
a diagonal effect if you want but, it's sometimes shaky on lteIE8, with that said if 
you choose to go down that road easily you can condition the layout for IE users horizontally.